# SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession and Principal of logged in user is never filled

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, openid

I have a spring boot application hosted on azure, which uses an azure ad b2c tenant as openid connect provider.

After the user is logged in via Azure AD B2C account or a social provider like Facebook or Google, the user can access the applications redirect url.
After logging in, the application can redirect the user to custom policies, which exist in the azure ad b2c tenant, and are secured via openid connect, and execute these.

I have however no access to the information of the logged in user via the userinfo endpoint, nor are the Principal parameter filled by spring security.

In addition the log contains error about the SecurityContext being empty or the user being anonymous, even after a successful login attempt by the user.

What do I need to change, that I can access the authenticated users information, such as username or email?

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

@GetMapping(value = "/home")
public String home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
 //Principal is always null
}
```

My security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
     http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/home*", "/dev", "/static/**","/customPolicyRedirect/**","/oauth2/**").permitAll()
             .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .oauth2Login(withDefaults());


 }
}
```

My application.yml

```
spring:
 data.rest.basePath: /api
 jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS: false
 messages:
 basename: localization/messages
 security:
  require-ssl: false
  oauth2:
  client:
    registration:
      azure:
        client-id: ${CLIENT_ID} 
        client-secret:  ${CLIENT_SECRET} 
        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        redirect-uri: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/home
        scope: openid
        client-authentication-method: post
    provider:
      azure:
        authorization-uri: https://thedevmycompany.b2clogin.com/thedevmycompany.onmicrosoft.com   /b2c_1a_signinv1_profile/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?ui_entity=srgssr
        token-uri: https://thedevmycompany.b2clogin.com/thedevmycompany.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signinv1_profile/oauth2/v2.0/token
        user-info-uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
        jwk-set-uri: https://thedevmycompany.b2clogin.com/thedevmycompany.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signinv1_profile/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

Log entries:

```
[..]
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 X-IMForwards: 20
 X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /
 CLIENT-IP: 217.162.1.240:25323
 X-ARR-LOG-ID: 1ad0ee82-3d74-4714-8073-8b715832cee6
 DISGUISED-HOST: myapplication.azurewebsites.net
 X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: myapplication
 WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: myapplication.azurewebsites.net
 X-Original-URL: /
 X-Forwarded-For: 217.162.1.240:25323
 
 ]
   o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=AA387E7A1BF46B097
   o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is AA387E7A1BF46B097
   o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /
   org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
   o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
   w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
   w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/login/oauth2/code/*'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
   o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 12 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
   o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@79768278: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 172.16.1.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 13 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
   o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID AA387E7A1BF46B097816689C3E3CC51F is invalid.
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 14 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 15 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/home*'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/dev'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/static/**'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/customPolicyRedirect/**'
   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth2/**'
   o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
   o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@79768278: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 172.16.1.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
   o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5bc96dec, returned: -1
   o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
 
 org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
 
[..]
      o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
[..]
       s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@6aafc904
       o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://myapplication.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/authorization/azure'
       o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5a4e31c9
       w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
       s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
       o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5ce93b5a:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12995]], Read from buffer: [0]
       o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
     
     java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:780) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
 
   o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5ce93b5a:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12995]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
   o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[http-nio-80-exec-6] latch=1
   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@1e3750d0].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5ce93b5a:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12995]])
  [nio-80-Acceptor] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting up[http-nio-80-Acceptor] latch=1
  [p-nio-80-exec-7] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@48fcffb4:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12997]], Read from buffer: [0]
  [p-nio-80-exec-7] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@48fcffb4:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12997]], Read direct from socket: [925]
  [p-nio-80-exec-7] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /oauth2/authorization/azure HTTP/1.1
 Host: myapplication.azurewebsites.net
 X-Client-IP: 217.162.1.240
 X-Client-Port: 25323
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Via: 1.1 somehost.zh.mycompany.ch:3128 (Cisco-WSA/11.7.1-006)
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
 Cookie: JSESSIONID=686A5DE6AD683B139E6D67176C7E4357
 Max-Forwards: 10
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 X-IMForwards: 20
 X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /oauth2/authorization/azure
 CLIENT-IP: 217.162.1.240:25323
 X-ARR-LOG-ID: a8f1fbf4-fa56-4c56-82ef-cb21370676ee
 DISGUISED-HOST: myapplication.azurewebsites.net
 X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: myapplication
 WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: myapplication.azurewebsites.net
 X-Original-URL: /oauth2/authorization/azure
 X-Forwarded-For: 217.162.1.240:25323
 
 ]
  o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=686A5DE6AD683B139E6D67176C7E4357
  o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 686A5DE6AD683B139E6D67176C7E4357
  o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /oauth2/authorization/azure
  org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
  o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@463b18db. A new one will be created.
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 5 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
  o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /oauth2/authorization/azure' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth2/authorization/azure at position 6 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter'
  o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/azure'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
  o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/azure'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
  org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
  o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'https://thedevmycompany.b2clogin.com/thedevmycompany.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_mettler_signinv1_profile/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?ui_entity=thessr&response_type=code&client_id=c2a5e81c-4b70-4077-b600-9e56cf69be62&scope=openid&state=tQ_6FRRaYbNpAYtgFAPH0U6yI-nTWPAwxT8GSu1tJKA%3D&redirect_uri=https://myapplication.azurewebsites.net/home&nonce=qjuRfc5vV_ajSngIAuhh-V40LUZRvwYkTDUXoUipeg0'
  o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5a4e31c9
  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
  s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
  o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@48fcffb4:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1c9e4d20:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.16.1.2:80 remote=/172.16.1.1:12997]], Read from buffer: [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for details about the user, so I would replace

```
scope: openid
```

with:

```
scope: openid email profile
```

This will allow the email and the user profile details to be returned to the client.